# How to spread list item content evenly and centered in HTML header?

Tags: html, css, header, html-lists, spacing

I currently have a Header in my HTML which is a Unordered List with List Items display = inline. What I am try to accomplish is to spread each of the 5 items into an equaled space (20% Width for each) and step them centered in their respective spaces. I was able to accomplish this with a lot of ease on the Footer, but instead of List Items, I used Divs for each of the Options. Can anyone help me do the same with list? I can redo it as Divs, but I'd like to at least know how to make the list work.

[How it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mVOs.jpg)

```css
html, body {
    margin:0;
 padding:0;
 height:100%;
}

a:link {
 text-decoration:none;
}

#page {
 position:relative;
 background:#E9EAEE;
 min-height:100%;
}

#header {
 position:fixed;
 left:0px;
 top:0px;
 z-index:1;
 width:100%;
 background-color:#3f5c99;
 padding-top:10px;
}

#header .holder {
 width:100%;
 float:left;
}

#header a {
 color:#ffffff;
 font-size:11px;
 font-weight: bold;
 padding:0px 10px 0 0;
 text-transform:uppercase;
}

#header li {
 display:inline;
 margin-left:-10px;
 padding:0 4px 0 6px;
 border-left: 1px solid #2F477A;
}

.logo {
 border-radius:2px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="page">
    <div id="header">
      <div class="holder">
        <ul>
          <li style="border-left:0px;"><a href="index.html"><img class="logo" src="../img/logo.png"/></a></li>
          <li><a href="../pt_br/comics.html">Comics</a></li>
          <li><a href="../pt_br/links.html" title="Links Favoritos"><img src="../img/friendOff.png"/></a></li>
          <li><a href="mailto:d.farielo@gmail.com" title="Fale Comigo"><img src="../img/mailChatOff.png"/></a></li>
          <li><a href="../wp/index.php" title="Meu Wordpress"><img src="../img/globeOff.png"/></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    ...
  </div>
</body>
```

I hope I was able to illustrate what I am trying to accomplish, but if it is still unclear please let me know. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like this ,I hope it will helps you.

```css
html, body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
}

a:link {
    text-decoration:none;
}

#page {
    position:relative;
    background:#E9EAEE;
    min-height:100%;
}

#header {
    position:fixed;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    z-index:1;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#3f5c99;
 
}

#header .holder {
    width:100%;
    float:left;
}

#header ul {
    display: table;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}


#header a {
    color: #ffffff;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

#header li {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 5px 0;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 20%;
}
#header li:after {
    border-left: 1px solid #2f477a;
    content: "";
    height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 8px;
}
.logo {
    border-radius:2px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="page">
    <div id="header">
      <div class="holder">
        <ul>
          <li style="border-left:0px;"><a href="index.html"><img class="logo" src="../img/logo.png"/></a></li>
          <li><a href="../pt_br/comics.html">Comics</a></li>
          <li><a href="../pt_br/links.html" title="Links Favoritos"><img src="../img/friendOff.png"/></a></li>
          <li><a href="mailto:d.farielo@gmail.com" title="Fale Comigo"><img src="../img/mailChatOff.png"/></a></li>
          <li><a href="../wp/index.php" title="Meu Wordpress"><img src="../img/globeOff.png"/></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    ...
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: This worked great! Thanks you so much! I was unaware of display:table in this situation ... I'll try to read a bit more about how it works. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

```
ul {
  display: flex;
}

#header li {
  ...
 flex: 1;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
 ...
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/234zzgn7/

Add this css. Ofcourse this is using flexbox which is something that I found to be extremely awesome. But you should investigate whether your users support it or not.

http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox

Comment: Seems to work great ... But I am trying to focus this site to be Mobile and from what I read, some of the Android Browser versions don't fully support Flexbox ... But still, always great to get an alternative to these issues ... Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Here try this. Changes are on `#header li` and `#header a`

```css
html, body {
    margin:0;
 padding:0;
 height:100%;
}

a:link {
 text-decoration:none;
}

#page {
 position:relative;
 background:#E9EAEE;
 min-height:100%;
}

#header {
 position:fixed;
 left:0px;
 top:0px;
 z-index:1;
 width:100%;
 background-color:#3f5c99;
 padding-top:10px;
}

#header .holder {
 width:100%;
 float:left;
}

#header a {
 color:#ffffff;
 font-size:11px;
 font-weight: bold;
 padding:0px 10px 0 0;
 text-transform:uppercase;
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

#header li {
 display:inline-block;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    width:20%;
 margin-left:-10px;
 padding:0 4px 0 6px;
 border-left: 1px solid #2F477A;
}

.logo {
 border-radius:2px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="page">
    <div id="header">
      <div class="holder">
        <ul>
          <li style="border-left:0px;"><a href="index.html"><img class="logo" src="../img/logo.png"/></a></li>
          <li><a href="../pt_br/comics.html">Comics</a></li>
          <li><a href="../pt_br/links.html" title="Links Favoritos"><img src="../img/friendOff.png"/></a></li>
          <li><a href="mailto:d.farielo@gmail.com" title="Fale Comigo"><img src="../img/mailChatOff.png"/></a></li>
          <li><a href="../wp/index.php" title="Meu Wordpress"><img src="../img/globeOff.png"/></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    ...
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: This also works but for some reason (might be something on my code) it throws one of the items to a second row ... Not sure if due to my paddings, margins or borders it thinks that 5 items with width of 20% are larger than 100%. Will look in to it to find what is causing this bug. :D

Comment: UPDATE: @XahedKamal, sorry, it was indeed my bad, it was an issue with my code, I had a broken tag ... Therefore this solution also works great! Thanks a bunch! :D